# Group by Range ms access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, range

I'd like to generate a table of counts, that shows how many times scores appeared in each range im ms access database.

database table

```
smsId int, Age text,etc.. 

Age   range  | number of occurrences
-------------------------------------
   0-9       |        11
  10-19      |        14
  20-29      |         3
   ...       |       ...
```

What is sql syntax

Comment: What kind of output you are expecting from what input? It might be helpful to edit your post with more details.

Comment: raw query is as like: select count(c_age) as no of occurences from sms where... group by age_range.what is exact sql ?

Comment: What are c_age and sms here? Please be clear on what you say. I don't see c_age column in your table.

Comment: it is  age field.count(age) as no of occurrences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`IIF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) expression to create the groups for each age range, then count the number of rows that are in each range:

```
select AgeRange, count(*) as NumberOfOccurrences
from
(
  SELECT 
    iif(age >= 0 and age <=9, "0-9", 
         iif(age>=10 and age <=19, "10-19", "20-29")) as AgeRange
  FROM yourtable
) d
group by AgeRange
```

If you have more Age Ranges, then you will add more values to the `IIF()`.

Another way you can do this is by adding a table that includes the age ranges for reporting.  A sample table could be:

```
create table AgeRange
(
  ageRangeStart number,
  ageRangeEnd number
);

insert into AgeRange values
(0, 9),
(10, 19);
```

If you create this table, then you can JOIN the table to your existing table for reporting on the ranges:

```
SELECT r.agerangestart &" - "&r.agerangeend as AgeRange, 
  count(*) as NumberOfOccurrences
from agerange r
inner join test t
  on t.age >= r.agerangestart
  and t.age <= r.agerangeend
group by r.agerangestart &" - "&r.agerangeend
```

Both of these queries will give a result:

```
+----------+---------------------+
| AgeRange | NumberOfOccurrences |
+----------+---------------------+
| 0 - 9    |                   6 |
| 10 - 19  |                   4 |
| 20 - 29  |                   2 |
+----------+---------------------+
```

Note: Both queries were tested in MS Access 2003.